# How to Add to Cart with Python using WooCommerce API?

Tags: python, mysql, wordpress, flask, woocommerce-rest-api

```
def reserve_image(image_id, user_id):
try:
    connection_images = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=host,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        database=database
    )
    connection_users = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=host,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        database=user_database
    )

    cursor_images = connection_images.cursor()
    cursor_users = connection_users.cursor()

    # Kullanıcının seçili imageini kontrol et
    cursor_users.execute("SELECT selected_image FROM users WHERE id = %s", (user_id,))
    selected_image = cursor_users.fetchone()[0]
    if selected_image:
        # Kullanıcının zaten seçili bir imagei varsa işlemi sonlandır
        flash("You have already selected a image.", "error")
        return

    # Imagein rezerve durumunu kontrol et
    cursor_images.execute("SELECT Reserved FROM images WHERE Image_ID = %s", (image_id,))
    reserved = cursor_images.fetchone()[0]
    if reserved:
        # Image zaten rezerve edilmişse işlemi sonlandır
        flash("The image is already reserved.", "error")
        return

    # WooCommerce API ile ödeme işlemi gerçekleştirme
    payment_data = {
        "payment_method": "stripe",  # Ödeme yöntemi
        "payment_method_title": "Credit Card",  # Ödeme yöntemi başlığı
        "set_paid": True  # Ödemeyi tamamlandı olarak işaretleme
    }
    response = wcapi.post("orders", payment_data)
    if response.status_code != 201 or response.json().get("payment_status") != "paid":
        # Ödeme başarısız ise hata mesajı göster
        flash("An error occurred while processing the payment.", "error")
        return

    # Ödeme başarılıysa veritabanında ödeme durumunu güncelleme
    payment_status = "Paid"  # Ödeme durumu
    cursor_users.execute("UPDATE users SET payment_status = %s WHERE id = %s", (payment_status, user_id))
    connection_users.commit()

    # Sepete ürün ekleme işlemi
    product_id = 17  # Eklenecek ürünün ID'si
    quantity = 1  # Eklenecek ürünün miktarı
    data = {
        "product_id": product_id,
        "quantity": quantity
    }
    response = wcapi.post("cart/items", data)
    if response.status_code != 201:
        # Sepete ekleme başarısız ise hata mesajı göster
        flash("An error occurred while adding the item to the cart.", "error")
        return

    # Image veritabanında rezervasyon işlemi
    cursor_images.execute("UPDATE images SET Reserved = TRUE WHERE Image_ID = %s", (image_id,))
    connection_images.commit()

    cursor_images.close()
    cursor_users.close()
    connection_images.close()
    connection_users.close()
except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    print("Hata oluştu:", error)`
```

So, my function is like this. I have a webpage including images that you can click and reserve them. I want to use the Reserve Button in a way that when the user clicks it. It will add to the cart to the user's cart, and it will work if it's paid. Then the user will Upload the image.

I have made a function to test the API and try to add manually to the cart.

```
wcapi = API(
    url=store_url,
    consumer_key=consumer_key,
    consumer_secret=consumer_secret,
    version="wc/v3"
)

# Eklenecek ürünün verileri
product_id = 17
quantity = 1

# Sepete ürün ekleme işlemi
def add_to_cart(product_id):
    data = {
        'product_id': product_id,
        'quantity': quantity,
    }
    print(data)#17
    response = wcapi.post("cart/items", data)
    print(response.json())
    # İstek sonucunu kontrol etme
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print('Ürün başarıyla sepete eklendi.')
    else:
        print('Ürün sepete eklenirken bir hata oluştu.')
        print(data)

# Sepete ürün ekleme işlemini çağırma
add_to_cart(product_id)
```

It gives "{'code': 'rest_no_route', 'message': 'İstek yöntemi ve bağlantıyla eşleşen güzergah bulunumadı', 'data': {'status': 404}}".

I get the product. {'product_id': 17, 'quantity': 1}

I am new. I know I might have critical thinking or practice wrong. Trying to solve this issue so that I can move on to other problems. Basically, there is only one product in my store. I want to be able to add that product to the cart. If I can manage to add to cart and pay and then refresh the album page accordingly. Then, it will be a success. If you have come here and read all, Thanks a lot in advance. Take care!

Comment: `rest_no_route` (and the 404) indicate that you're trying to hit a non-existent REST route, or one that doesn't respond on the method you're trying (eg it's only a `GET` route and you're trying to `POST`). Are you *sure* the URL is correct and that it accepts the method?

Comment: Yes, I double checked it. I manually wrote the URL for `/cart` sadly. It does not update.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using the wrong URL for adding items to the cart in WooCommerce. To add items to the cart, you should use the correct endpoint, which follows the format:

```
BaseURL + wp-json/wc/store/v1/cart/add-item
```

Here's an example of how to construct the request in your Pyhton code:

```
import requests

# Define your WooCommerce store URL, consumer key, and consumer secret
base_url = 'https://your-woocommerce-store.com'
consumer_key = 'your-consumer-key'
consumer_secret = 'your-consumer-secret'

# Define the endpoint to add items to the cart
add_item_endpoint = '/wp-json/wc/store/v1/cart/add-item'

# Construct the full API URL
api_url = base_url + add_item_endpoint

# Define the product data you want to add to the cart
product_data = {
    'product_id': 17,
    'quantity': 1
 }

# Send the POST request to add the product to the cart
response = requests.post(api_url, json=product_data, auth=(consumer_key, 
consumer_secret))

if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Product added to the cart successfully.")
    # You can handle the response data here if needed.
else:
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
```

Make sure to replace 'your-woocommerce-store.com', 'your-consumer-key', and 'your-consumer-secret' with your actual WooCommerce store's details. This should allow you to correctly add items to the cart in your WooCommerce store using the REST API.

If you encounter any further issues, double-check your authentication details and ensure that your WooCommerce store is correctly configured to accept API requests.